# Any system to write code with multiple users online in real time like a shared google docs?

Tags: python, editor

Is there any free system to write code with multiple users online in real time like a shared google docs? Google docs would work just fine for us if only it could do some color-highlighting.

Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar ground covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873780/best-editor-for-remote-pair-programming

..and here: https://superuser.com/questions/10088/google-docs-syntax-highlight

..and here: [Is there any IDE or Source Control System inspired by Google Docs collaborative mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922169/is-there-any-ide-or-source-control-system-inspired-by-google-docs-collaborative-m)

I hope one of the above helps!
N

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla Skywriter](https://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/) (unfortunately far down in the answers of Nick Cartwright's linked question) should meet the criteria.